# Process.Start throws an exception when trying to open a website with a hyperlink

Tags: c#, wpf

This code throws an `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception` in my `RequestNavigate` event handler.

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
e.Handled = true;
```

[image: Exception in Visual Studio]

This is my XAML code:

```
<TextBlock Margin="0 0 40 40" FontSize="13" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
   <Hyperlink Foreground="Snow" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate" NavigateUri="http://www.google.com">Bizning jamoa bilan tanishishni</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Just Process.Start(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri); it is fine. Try to run as an administrator. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.0

Answer (score 7):

You need to set `UseShellExecute` to `true`.

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri) {UseShellExecute = true});
```

From the documentation of [`ProcessStartInfo.FileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.filename?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_FileName):

> If UseShellExecute is true, you can start any document and perform operations on the file, such as printing, with the Process component. When UseShellExecute is false, you can start only executables with the Process component.

The [default value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/fx-core#change-in-default-value-of-useshellexecute) of `UseShellExecute` varies in .NET Core and .NET Framework.

> ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute has a default value of false on .NET Core. On .NET Framework, its default value is true.

Comment: ooooo Thanks bro. it has fixed

Comment: That's such a stupid difference to have between .NET Core and .NET Framework, luckily there are people like you to help find these kind of details!

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell it to shellexecute as well using a processstartinfo.

The below is working code which avoids this error:

```
hyper.RequestNavigate += (o, e) => 
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.ToString()) { UseShellExecute = true });
```

This behaviour is a recent change.

You didn't used to need that shellexecute and you will likely see code which doesn't use it posted in old answers on SO.

Comment: The change was not introduced to satisfy security concerns: _"This change was introduced in .NET Core for performance reasons. Typically, Process.Start is used to launch an application directly. Launching an app directly does not need to involve the Windows shell and incur the associated performance cost. To make this default case faster, .NET Core changes the default value of ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute to false. You can opt in to the slower path if you need it."_ ([Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/fx-core#change-description)).